# Diferenciar un barplot dependiendo de la etiqueta del eje x

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe con muchas entradas (1492 obs de 5 variables) similar a este dataframe:

```
R.PV002_f:
                  POS_IN      POS_FI      COVERAGE    REGION
                     1         120          9248     3a.protein
                   120         135          9248     3a.protein
                   136         159          5748     CP
                   250         251          3248     CP
                   252         358          1248     CP
                   359         500          4248     CP
```

la cual he creado un barplot usando esta función:

```
   barplot(R.PV002_f$COVERAGE)
```

Y obtengo una imagen como esta:

[image: Barplot]

Me gustaría separar el barplot (ya sea con una etiqueta abajo o con diferentes colores que la parte de más a la izquierda es 3a.protein y la de la derecha es CP. Pero no se como hacerlo ni añadile etiquetas al eje x.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola te agrego unos ejemplos que espero te puedan ayudar

Creamos una data.frame como el tuyo

```
df<-data.frame(COVERAGE =sample(9000:60000,1000),
               REGION=c(rep("3a.protein",500),rep("Cp",500)))
```

Ahora agregamos una columna auxiliar con colores dependiendo del valor de `REGION`

```
df$color<-NULL
df$color[df$REGION=="3a.protein"]<-rgb(0.3,0.1,0.4,0.6)
df$color[df$REGION=="Cp"]<-rgb(0.3,0.5,0.4,0.6)
```

Para agregar nombres puedes usar el argumento `names.arg`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Para agregar color usaremos la columna auxiliar que creamos antes y el argumento `color`. En tu caso también es importante pasar los colores al argumento `border`, ya que tienes muchas columnas y si no lo haces solo se notara el color negro de los bordes de las columnas. También puedes lograr un resultado similar con `border=NA`.

```
barplot(df$COVERAGE,border = df$color,col=df$color)
#barplot(df$COVERAGE,border = NA,col=df$color)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si combinas los dos pasos anteriores podrías obtener una gráfica con colores y con los nombres en el eje x. Pero te recomiendo agregar unas etiquetas que nos hablen del color

```
barplot(df$COVERAGE,border = df$color,col=df$color)
legend("bottom", legend = c("3a.protein","Cp") , 
       col = c(rgb(0.3,0.1,0.4,0.6) , rgb(0.3,0.5,0.4,0.6)),
       bty = "o", pch=20 , pt.cex = 2, horiz = T,
       box.col ="white")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Funciona a la perfección Rolando, me quedo con el último ejemplo para lo que necesito. Solo hay una pega.. la caja de la leyenda es muy grande y solapa toda la gráfica ¿Cómo puedo cambiarlo? Muchas gracias

Comment: Perdona... ¿Cómo puedo hacer que la caja de texto de la leyenda se haga más pequeño? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Puedes usar el parámetro **cex=0.7** dentro de la función **legend()**. Si aun te parece demasiado grande puedes disminuir el valor de **cex**.

Comment: Disminuye el tamaño de la letra pero no de la caja, que otra alternativa me da ? gracias de antemano

Comment: Es probable que tu ventana de visualización de gráficas sea demasiado pequeña. Puedes definir el tamaño  de la ventana con **windows(height = 7, width = 11)**

Answer (score 1):

Antes de nada, mencionar que si bien `barplot` solo requiere el parámetro `height` para funcionar, el caso de uso en la pregunta *es incorrecto* ya que solo deberían haber 2 columnas como resultado del gráfico, uno para CP y el otro para 3a.protein con lo cual `barplot(COVERAGE~ REGION, data = df)` resolveria el problema.

Para ver un caso de uso correcto de los **gráficos de barra** usando `barplot` puedes revisar los ejemplos de la documentación de R mediante `help("barplot")`.

Ahora, con más de 10 años de creación y una estructura determinada por la *Gramática de los Gráficos*, es recomendable instalar y usar el paquete `ggplot2` en lugar de `base` para todo lo que sean gráficos estáticos.

Instalar y usar `ggplot2`:

```
    install.packages("ggplot2")
    library("ggplot2")
```

Digamos que tus datos son:

```
df <- data.frame(COVERAGE=c(4200, 6099),
             REGION=c("3a.protein", "CP"))
```

Entonces el código para lo que necesitabas sería

```
p<-ggplot(df, aes(x=REGION, y=COVERAGE, fill=REGION))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  theme_minimal()
p
```

[image: barplot diferenciado según los valores de X]

Comment: Hola Dante, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Tu script funciona bien, pero se ajusta un poco más lo que respondió Rolando. No obstante, muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: En ese caso sería mas apropiado un areaplot. Es decir, si, puedes hacer un areaplot usando `boxplot` pero es computacionalmente más eficiente usar la herramienta específica para la visualización específica. Éxitos.